# Obtain all issues in a project with multiple versions via Redmine REST API?

Tags: api, rest, redmine

I would like to obtain all issues for a Redmine test project using the [Redmine REST API](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues).

If I look at my test project’s Roadmap in the Redmine web interface (with Show Completed Versions) I see 3 versions and a total of 10 + 5 + 13 issues.

But when I query those issues with `GET /issues.json?project_id=...&key=...` I get only 13 issues back. Could it be that only the issues for the latest version (by what metric?) are returned? This does not seem to be mentioned in the documentation but could explain the mismatch.

When I query for the other 10 (and then 5) issues with `GET /issues.json?project_id=...&fixed_version_id=...&key=...` I get 0 issues back (why?) and 0 + 0 + 13 could also explain the mismatch.

So how can I obtain all 10 + 5 + 13 issues via the Redmine REST API?

Comment: Have you tried filter parameter `status_id=*` in your request to get both open and closed issues? REST API returns only open issues when status_id is not specified.

Comment: @Michael Yes, that meanwhile has turned out to be the right approach. If you want to write it up as an answer, I can accept it and thereby close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redmine REST API returns only open issues by default. If you want to retrieve issues regardless their status, use the `status_id=*` parameter.